# How to embed an executable file with a input file and output the result as a file in Php?

Tags: php

To embed a executable file I have written this code

```
<?php     
$file = "C:/embed";    
$output = exec($file);    
echo $output;
?>
```

Now how can I give the input command, where **embed.in** is the file name?

> "embed >embed.in"

Comment: Are you talking about stdin here?

Comment: yes i wanted to give the filename "embed.in" as an input for the .exe program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $file = "C:/embed > embed.in";
```

What's wrong with above?

Comment: the output will be in a file called embed.in that's what the command is asking it to do.

Comment: no i wanted to give the filename "embed.in" as an input for the .exe program

Comment: Find out the command you need to use on the command line and then execute that via the exec command in php.  It sounds like you are unsure of the command you need to execute in the first place.  One you have that the php part will be much easier.